# Getting methods that return a specific type using GetMethods

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using the following method to insert into a comboBox a list of the names of the methods in the class.

```
Type t = typeof(Functions);
// public instance methods 
MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var methodsNames = methods.Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();
// add them to combobox
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(methodsNames);
```

I want it to contain only the ones who return a specific type (int for example).

if I have those methods:

```
    public static int CountSameSizes(BinTreeNode<string> BT)
    public static string CountLeaves(BinTreeNode<string> BT)
    public static string CountAtLeastOneLeaf(BinTreeNode<string> BT)
```

I want it to return only the first one.

Comment: @Servy I dont need anyone to correct my question thank you very much.
Yes, my grammer isnt the best (im Israeli).

Comment: I fixed some of the more obvious problems with the question because they bothered me.  I didn't fix *every single* problem with the question partly to maintain your voice, and partly because I didn't want to take the time for a full re-write.  This is a community maintained site in which, by participating, you are implicitly giving permission for your posts to be improved (within certain editing guidelines).

Comment: @Servy yea whatever bro...
if we are allready chatting here's a question - where do i post a question about "what is the most suitable way to show program info and change log". i dunno if to add a winform to my program or ect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Cast<MethodInfo>()
    .Where(method => method.ReturnType == typeof(int))
```

Comment: tried it, i get this message:

Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>' to 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ---\BinTreeNode\BinTreeNode\Form1.cs 91 36 BinTreeNode

Comment: Sorry, it's because `GetMethods` doesn't return a strongly typed `IEnumerable`. Try the edited solution.

Comment: now im getting Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.MethodInfo>' to 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) ---\BinTreeNode\\BinTreeNode\Form1.cs 91 36 BinTreeNode

which i think is the same error

Comment: Are you sure you've recompiled with the edited version? I don't get any problems.

Comment: @EliranBreitbart - Just call `ToArray` on the sequence.

Comment: var methodsNames = methods.Cast<MethodInfo>().Where(method => method.ReturnType == typeof(int)).Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();
this is the code i used to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   public IEnumerable<string> GetMethodsOfReturnType(Type cls, Type ret)
    {
       var methods = cls.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
       var retMethods = methods.Where(m => m.ReturnType.IsSubclassOf(ret) || m.ReturnType == ret)
                               .Select(m => m.Name);
       return retMethods;
    }
```

Comment: i never used a IEnumerable<string>, i dont really know if what you gave will be good for my program.